# Changing R default values in boxplot (upper and lower limits)...can i use `boxplot.stats`

Tags: r, plot, boxplot

As a new R user, I would like to change the default values of the whiskers for `boxplot(x)`.

My understanding is the *standard definition of Q3+1.5IQR for the upper limit & Q1-1.5IQR* is used for the end of the whiskers.

However I need to change this, so I can have the top and bottom whisker represent the *98th and 2nd percentile* respectively.

Could someone provide some advice on how this can be done? Based on different questions on this site I believe it has something to do with `boxplot.stats` but am unsure of what to do.

Any help would be very useful - thank you!

**Update1** - My data includes multiple boxplots in one plot (i.e. 17 datagroups with hundreds of data points read in via .csv file). My figure includes boxplots for 17 datagroups in the single plot and I would like to do this for all the datagroups in my plot.

**Update2**- I need to change the upper & lower limits to the 98th & 2nd percentile respectively so only data above those points are shown as outliers.

Comment: @Pascal. thanks. Unfortunately everytime I've tried obtaining libraries the past few days it hasn't worked, but will hopefully check out StatDA soon. I was thinking there might be a way to do it in the meantime using `boxplot.stats'.

Comment: @Pascal: I have tried changing "range" and it works to shift the whiskers. But I specifically need to get it to 98th & 2nd percentiles, so trying to find a way to set that percentile via `boxplot.stats` for the time being.